# Handling ORA-01400 exception in a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to handle inserting

> null exception (ORA-01400)

within `COMPOUND Trigger`?

I have a table with some `NOT NULL` columns and `compound trigger` enabled on this table. When I try to `insert` just one record with `null` values for `not null` columns I've got an error which looks like invisible for the trigger. I couldn't handle it in any way. All commands from `BEFORE EACH ROW` block are executed and none of the commands from `AFTER EACH ROW` is executed neither commands from `EXCEPTION` block.

Comment: Don't do it  this way . please!! . Let Oracle handle constraints the way it does..You handle `NULL`s in your `insert into`

Comment: Look, my intention is to have logged all operations performed on database, especially errors. Since the data is loaded from Oracle independed source, I haven't even information that something went wrong. Do you have idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. The real issue is that you have a data loading process with inadequate (or non-existent?) logging. Solving this problem with triggers is computationally expensive, because the trigger fires for each row and is way less efficient that using Oracle's built-in constraint functionality. Also it's a lot of code to write (or generate) and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW triggers before inserting into the table for each row

AFTER INSERT FOR EACH ROW triggers **after** inserting into the table for each row

If the INSERT fails due to ORA-01400 or any other error, then the AFTER INSERT will not be reached, and hence not executed. This also true for any exception on the triggers, as the exception was not raised during trigger execution but during insert itself

If you want to handle NULL values when inserting, you can assign the columns certain value if null using the BEFORE INSERT trigger

```
if :NEW.column_name is null then
    :NEW.column_name := <value if null> -- you can also select from other table into :NEW.column_name
end if;
```

Or you can use defaul value on the column

If you want the trigger to raise an exception if the value of a column is null, you can raise an exception within the BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER after check

```
create or replace 
trigger test_trigger
before insert on table1
for each row
is
    custom_exception exception;
begin
   if :NEW.column_name is null then
       raise custom_exception;
   end if;
exception
   when custom_exception then
      do something...
end;
```

Comment: One of the main advantages of declaring columns NOT NULL is to allow the database to handle everything for us. Why own a dog and bark yourself?

Comment: you might be inserting into the table from various sources, and hence, based on certain condition, assign what is null to a default value! You can assign a default value to a column by definition, but that has limited ability. You want the dog not to bark at your obnoxious looking friends :)

Comment: The question posits standalone mandatory columns. More sophisticated conditional checks would require a Table-level Check Constraint. Your scenario seems like a very niche edge case.

Comment: Could be, but then the question mentioned exceptions within triggers for a reason I don't know of. Hence, the answer touched on possible use of exceptions within triggers. Main idea is that, a default value can be assigned by the trigger, if cannot be assigned by the otherwise straight-forward default statement